# Django-allauth login page is too simple

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth, django-socialauth, django-login

I have created a project in which I provided a login system. I also want to provide a login with the google option. I have installed Django-allath and made the necessary changes to log in and retrieve the necessary data. But when I click on login with google it **sends me to the simple login page** and after continuing it redirects me to the google login page. I want when I click on login with google, the application should send me to the google login page.
Please help me.

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/480/000000/google-logo.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what your problem is but use django social auth.

The docs are straight forward. you van use it in combination with all auth

[docs](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html)

Comment: exactly, using social auth. is a time saver